# Can I load only specific data from source file into HIVE table?

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive, load

I have a pipe delimited text file with 400 values. Out of which I need to load only 40 values at positions[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 15, 17, 18, 20...] into my Hive table, how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

By the book: create an `EXTERNAL` table to map your Text file, with 400 columns; create a managed table with 40 columns; then use SQL to `INSERT INTO TABLE target SELECT col1, col2, col4, ..., col72 FROM wide_source`

Actually, you don't need to map all 400 columns -- stop at the last column that you want to use in SQL and ignore the rest.

Comment: Thanks, so basically I should load all the data into Table A and create a second Table B to SELECT the specific columns from Table B? My last column in 145 so while creating Table A I can stop at 145 right? Is there an advantage of going for EXTERNAL table for the first?

Comment: EXTERNAL means that you don't "load" anything in Hive. You just ask Hive to read from a file (or a bunch of files) that was dumped there by another process, and provide the column mapping.